# How to incrementally print the chars in a String in Python

Tags: python

```
s = 'fo12--'
for a in s:
    a+= 1
    print(s[a])
```

I would expect

> ```
> f  o  1  2 - -
> ```

but getting some type error. I can guess 'a' is a int here, but how can I improve this code

Comment: In fact `a` is not an it is a character, so that is causing the type error

Comment: *"I can guess 'a' is a int here"* I recommend you stop guessing and start debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (for `Python 3`):

```
s = 'fo12--'
for a in s:
    print(a, end = " ")
```

For `Python 2`:

```
s = 'fo12--'
for a in s:
    print a,
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/61Yvbg).

---

You do not need to fiddle with the   `a[index]` syntax known from other programming languages. If you want to have the index as well, `enumerate()` is your friend:

```
s = 'fo12--'
for idx, char in enumerate(s):
    # char holds the actual character
    # idx is an increasing integer, starting from zero
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what your title says would just be:

```
s = 'fo12--'
for i in s:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

But there are some fundamental problems with the code and the understanding of how it should perform (you saying that you guess 'a' is an `int`).

I would certainly suggest going through a Python basics program or tutorial first, it will help you get to grips with the basics and understand what is happening under the hood, so to speak.

Good luck and enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Python 2/3:

Without variable:

```
print(' '.join("fo12--"))
```

With a variable:

```
a = "fo12--"
print(' '.join(a))
```

The `join` method iterates through object and join them with a given string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `a` both for the individual characters of `s` (your `for a in s`) AND as an index into that string.  Either will work, but you can't use it for both at the same time.